# Turn Parked Domains into Addon Domains with php

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, redirect, server

Duo to limitation of my host I want to have multiple websites without addon domain and with parked domain. Currently I'm using follow script and works

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'www.xxxxxx.com') {
        include('sale.html');
}
else {
        include('personal.html'); 
}
```

But I want to put each of the websites in a separated folder (they are all in public_html now) and because the third website is a Wordpress, I have problem with URLs. Can you help me to fix that?

Comment: You can use .htacces for that.

Comment: You are trying to bypass limitations set by your host? I feel like this probably violates their terms of use.

Comment: what you seem to be saying is you want to completely refactor your web-server, stratifying the domains/sites.  ugh.  there is no easy way home from where you are.